# I am having trouble creating the database in flask in vsc and in windows 10. Can someone help solve the problem?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I need to create the database.

This is what I need to type to create the database.

```
from flaskblog import db
from flaskblog.models import User, Post, etc  
db.create_all()
```

I start by typing `python` into  powershell in visual studio code.

Then I type `from flaskblog import db` and get the error

ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'flaskblog' (C:\Users\n\OneDrive\Desktop\codingfiles2use\flaskblog_*init*_.py)

Here is my file tree.
[file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGVEs.png)

How do I fix this? Thanks

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask  
# make SQLAlchemy work 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# make login work
from flask_login import LoginManager# user_loaded_from_header
# make crf protection work 
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect





# setup databases
db = SQLAlchemy()
# Make Login user variable work ?
login_manager = LoginManager()
# Setup CSRF protection. This allows html forms to work and be secure.  
csrf = CSRFProtect()


# imports config from config.py
from flaskblog.config import Config


def create_app(config_class=Config): 
    app = Flask(__name__) 
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False 
    # what does this do?
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    csrf.init_app(app)
    
    from flaskblog.usersinfo.routes import usersinfo
    # why lowercse b in blueprints ?
    app.register_blueprint(usersinfo)
    return app 

from .models import User 

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get_by_id(user_id)
```

**run.py**

```
from flaskblog.app import create_app
app = create_app()
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**config.py**

```
import os     

class Config:
    # Setup CSRF secret key
    SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///tmp/test.db'
```

when I type

```
from flaskblog import db
from flaskblog.models import User   
db.create_all()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1094, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1071, in _execute_for_all_tables   
    app = self.get_app(app)
  File "C:\Users\nmyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1042, in get_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

I try to finish the code by adding one of the different code blocks and it doesn't work I still get an error. I tried all the code blocks how do I fix this?

http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.

Comment: can you paste the code for the init.py file in flaskblog and your run.py also.

Comment: init.py is an blank file. I uploaded run.py and app.py.

Comment: Do this from flaskbog.app import db.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions I updated my question. I tried @charchit method I even uploaded the code from the link.  http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use app_context

run all these commands in terminal

```
from flaskblog.app import db,create_app
from flaskblog.models import User  
app = create_app()
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

Comment: I type the commands into powershell and the screen just sits there. Then I press enter and get the following error located at the pastebin link. https://pastebin.com/ai9ewPmu
How do I fix this? I am going to add config.py to the code.

Comment: It is difficult for me to why this error comes , if you can give me the code through github or discord `charchit#8198` , so that I can test on my own.

Comment: Can I post my github here https://github.com/NML240/flaskblog2 

Thanks.

Comment: You are using factory design in a wrong way, I need to change the structure of your folder and code , if I would be able to contaact you it would be better. for factory design see this example . https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog/12-Error-Pages

Comment: sure I will contact you on discord.  Thanks.